# OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'time_table.id' in 'field list'")

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I have a legacy database not created by django with the following table:

```
$ describe `time`; 
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| data          | varchar(16)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| source        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| source_origin | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| sys_updated   | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I get the model of this table by `inspectdb`:

```
class Time(models.Model):
    data = models.ForeignKey('a_table', models.DO_NOTHING)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    source_origin = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    sys_updated = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'time'
        unique_together = (('data', 'source_origin'),)
```

A have a simple serializer:

```
class TimeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Time
        fields = ('data', 'source', 'source_origin', 'sys_updated')
```

And a simple `view`:

```
class TimeList(generics.ListAPIView):
    """ Retrieves all data. """
    queryset = Time.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimeSerializer
```

When I try to access this from, let's say, `localhost:8765/time/`, I'm getting the following error:

```
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'time.id' in 'field list'")
```

**My question**:
Is it posible to have a table to the django rest without an id?
I don't want to add an id at my table.

I found some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253817/mysql-gives-an-unknown-column-user-id-in-field-list-error-using-djangos-a) in the wild, but it did not help.

Comment: As Ivan says, Django requires each model to have a primary key. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33085716/113962) suggested you could work around it by using `values()`. However, I don't know whether it would be possible to change the rest framework serializer to use `values()` rather than a regular queryset.

Answer (score 5):

From the doc:

> Each model requires exactly one field to have primary_key=True (either
>   explicitly declared or automatically added).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

So I'm afraid the answer is no. You can try and set the primary_key=True on one of the other fields if that works for you..

Comment: It is not a good solution but if I add `primary_key=True` to one of the other fields it is working